# How to extract a string using JavaScript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, icalendar

I'm trying to extract a substring from a file with JavaScript Regex. Here is a slice from the file :

```
DATE:20091201T220000
SUMMARY:Dad's birthday
```

the field I want to extract is "Summary". Here is the approach:

```
extractSummary : function(iCalContent) {
  /*
  input : iCal file content
  return : Event summary
  */
  var arr = iCalContent.match(/^SUMMARY\:(.)*$/g);
  return(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to use the `m` [flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax):

> multiline; treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working
>   over multiple lines (i.e., match the beginning or end of each line
>   (delimited by \n or \r), not only the very beginning or end of the
>   whole input string)

Also put the `*` in the right place:

```
"DATE:20091201T220000\r\nSUMMARY:Dad's birthday".match(/^SUMMARY\:(.*)$/gm);
//------------------------------------------------------------------^    ^
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 168):

```
function extractSummary(iCalContent) {
  var rx = /\nSUMMARY:(.*)\n/g;
  var arr = rx.exec(iCalContent);
  return arr[1]; 
}
```

You need these changes:

- Put the `*` inside the parenthesis as
  suggested above. Otherwise your matching
  group will contain only one
  character.
- Get rid of the `^` and `$`. With the global option they match on start and end of the full string, rather than on start and end of lines. Match on explicit newlines instead.
- I suppose you want the matching group (what's
  inside the parenthesis) rather than
  the full array? `arr[0]` is
  the full match (`"\nSUMMARY:..."`) and
  the next indexes contain the group
  matches.
- String.match(regexp) is
  supposed to return an array with the
  matches. In my browser it doesn't (Safari on Mac returns only the full
  match, not the groups), but
  Regexp.exec(string) works.

Comment: I would combine this with @barkmadley 's `|| [null, null]` since if the match fails, `arr` would be null and `arr[1]` would throw an exception

Answer (score 29):

Your regular expression most likely wants to be

```
/\nSUMMARY:(.*)$/g
```

A helpful little trick I like to use is to default assign on match with an array.

```
var arr = iCalContent.match(/\nSUMMARY:(.*)$/g) || [""]; //could also use null for empty value
return arr[0];
```

This way you don't get annoying type errors when you go to use `arr`

Comment: `match` returns a null if there is no _match_

Comment: returning `arr[0]` will return the input string. if you want to return the capture group, you need to return `arr[1]`. And your default of `[""]` would need to change to `["",""]`.

Answer (score 10):

`(.*)` instead of `(.)*` would be a start. The latter will only capture the last character on the line.

Also, no need to escape the `:`.

Answer (score 10):

This code works:

```js
let str = "governance[string_i_want]"; 
let res = str.match(/[^governance\[](.*)[^\]]/g);
console.log(res);
```

res will equal "string_i_want". However, in this example res is still an array, so do not treat res like a string.

By grouping the characters I do not want, using [^string], and matching on what is between the brackets, the code extracts the string I want!

You can try it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_match_regexp

Good luck.

Comment: negative lookup with fail with any of the forbidden letters are present in the required string.

Answer (score 5):

You should use this :

```
var arr = iCalContent.match(/^SUMMARY\:(.)*$/g);
return(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score -2):

this is how you can parse iCal files with javascript

```
    function calParse(str) {

        function parse() {
            var obj = {};
            while(str.length) {
                var p = str.shift().split(":");
                var k = p.shift(), p = p.join();
                switch(k) {
                    case "BEGIN":
                        obj[p] = parse();
                        break;
                    case "END":
                        return obj;
                    default:
                        obj[k] = p;
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
        str = str.replace(/\n /g, " ").split("\n");
        return parse().VCALENDAR;
    }

    example = 
    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n'+
    'VERSION:2.0\n'+
    'PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN\n'+
    'BEGIN:VEVENT\n'+
    'DTSTART:19970714T170000Z\n'+
    'DTEND:19970715T035959Z\n'+
    'SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party\n'+
    'END:VEVENT\n'+
    'END:VCALENDAR\n'


    cal = calParse(example);
    alert(cal.VEVENT.SUMMARY);
```