# Javascript extract unknown number in string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have a string ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctrl06_lblCountDown that will come into a javascript function using sender from my asp.net button control...

```
<asp:Button ID="buttStartTimer" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="javascript:countdown(this);" Text="Start" />
```

function test(sender) {

}

The need to get the number directly following  ctrl, In the example above it would be 06 (ctrl06_lblCountDown)

How can I extract this number using javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Is it always right after the string "ctrl"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a string using Javascript Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707299/how-to-extract-a-string-using-javascript-regex)

Comment: can you provide a few of the different strings so we can see what varies between each one?

Comment: I tried both of the answers below but neither returned a value.
The ctrl output number could be any number i.e _ctrl45_
They will just be numbers though.

Comment: @SheriTrager, I've added a working example to my answer. have a look at this too: http://jsfiddle.net/RXGb2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctrl06_lblCountDown",
    result = str.match(/.*ctrl(\d+).*/)[1];
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RXGb2/

Comment: I saw your example and it works great in jsfiddle, but not in my application.  I am using asp.net 4, would that matter.  
I switched to IE and get error... SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'match'

Comment: Are you sure the `match` is called with a string?

Comment: I did check to see what sender was and it was "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctrl2_buttStartTime"
I reference sender in my asp.net button control using onclientclick="javascript:countdown(this);"
I know I must be doing something wrong which is affecting the answers I've been getting.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I just did an alert to see what sender was and it the control.  I will try using sender.id

Comment: Added id to sender and now it's a string... I guess I've been working on this to long... so Sorry:-(. 
I now get the number and it works like a champ!  Thanks so much for your help and making me think.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract is using regex easily:

```
var str = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctrl06_lblCountDown";
var num = parseInt(str.match(/_ctrl([\d]*)_/)[1], 10);
```

---

*Safer way:*

```
var str = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctrl06_lblCountDown";
var parts = str.match(/_ctrl([\d]*)_/), num;
if(parts.length > 1) {
    num = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP want's the result to be `06` and not `6`

Comment: Then don't `parseInt()`, rest is same.

Comment: I will try it without the parseint
I also checked to make sure sender was sending the right information and it is.  This is what I get from sender...
"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctrl2_buttStartTimer"

Comment: I switched to IE and get error...
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'match'

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var str = 'ctrl06_lblCountDown',
    numericArray = [],
    numericString,
    num,
    i=0,
    len = 0;


numericArray = str.match(/[0-9]/g);

len = numericArray.length;

numericString = '';
for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    numericString += numericArray[i];

}

num = parseInt(numericString,10);
```