# How to extract particular block from sentence using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to extract particular block from a string.

```
[Main Menu,128</Main Menu][Gallery Menu,24</Gallery Menu][Nolcard Menu,5</Nolcard Menu][Feedback form,1</Feedback form]
```

How can I get only `[Main Menu,128</Main Menu]`

or `[Gallery Menu,24</Gallery Menu]`

by considering [XXX and /XXXX] .

using jQuery

Comment: This formatting is a little weird, but you can try using Regex with Javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707299/how-to-extract-a-string-using-javascript-regex

Comment: What is fixed and what can be allowed to change in those strings "Main Menu" and "Gallery Menu"?

Comment: [Main Menu,128</Main Menu][Gallery Menu,24</Gallery Menu][Nolcard Menu,5</Nolcard Menu][Feedback form,1</Feedback form]   ------ This is complete string When I send to extract 'Main Menu' then I will get [Main Menu,128</Main Menu] as an output.