# extract particular piece of text through javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript

I would like to extract particular piece of text `MH4` from the string `S12345-MH4-PX` through javascript regular expressions.

The desired output should be MH4.

Comment: Why regular expressions? `string.split('-')[1]` gives desired output for all strings in that format.

Comment: I would like to see what you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707299/how-to-extract-a-string-using-javascript-regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
var input = 'S12345-MH4-PX';    
var reg = /\-(.*)-/g;

var matches = reg.exec(input);

console.log(matches[1]);
```