# How can I use regex to only show characters after a specific string

Tags: regex

I have strings that could look like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/1234
http://mywebsite.com/foo
http://mywebsite.com/bar
http://google.com
```

I want to use a regex to only grab the strings that are preceeded with "http://mywebsite.com/" and only contain letters after that (not numbers). So in my example, the following strings would be valid:

```
http://mywebsite.com/foo
http://mywebsite.com/bar
```

so far I have a regex that looks like this:

```
"http://mywebsite.com/[a-zA-Z]+"
```

but I'm not getting any results

Comment: Please tag the language you're using

Comment: You probably need to escape the slashes: use `\/` instead of `/`

Comment: In addition to @GalAbra's comments, depending on what you mean by "grab", you might need a capture group, using `(` and `)`, in the regex; where to put them of course depends on how much of the desired strings you want to "grab"

Comment: What tool/language are you using? JavaScript? Then see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707299/how-to-extract-a-string-using-javascript-regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape the slashes and dot using backslashes, but you should also be using `$` at the end of your regex to make sure that there are no numbers (or other disallowed characters) following the match:

```
http:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/[a-zA-Z]+$
```

This does presume that you have each string occupying its own line in the input, or that there is not any other information after each string you are testing.

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/ESXGN9/2)

---

To "grab" the string after the final slash, use a capturing group:

```
http:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/([a-zA-Z]+)$
```

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/oIOR3B/1)

Then using your programming language, you can access the value stored in that group for each match. Or, if your regex flavour supports the `\K` sequence you could use:

```
http:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/\K[a-zA-Z]+$
```

to avoid the capturing group altogether.

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/pYjdtT/1)