# Skip the same string value

Tags: javascript, string, linefeed

```js
var data = "20 FIXED\r\n7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200\r\n 9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200\r\nLOAD 1 LOADTYPE Dead  TITLE DEAD";


function pullBetTwoStrings(data, str1, str2) {

 return data.split(str1)[1].split(str2)[0].trim();
}

var support_FBnode_data = pullBetTwoStrings(data, "FIXED", "LOAD" );
console.log(pullBetTwoStrings(data,"FIXED", "LOAD"));
```

I have a list of string in this kind of format:

```
var data = "20 FIXED\r\n
           7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200\r\n
           9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200\r\n
           LOAD 1 LOADTYPE Dead  TITLE DEAD"
```

How do i get the middle ones only? I want to achieve like this:

```
7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200
9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200
```

I have a code below that i use in order to get the in between data but it stops whenever it reaches the FIXED string again.

```
function pullBetTwoStrings(data, str1, str2) {

 return data.split(str1)[1].split(str2)[0].trim();
}

var support_FBnode_data = pullBetTwoStrings(data, "FIXED", "LOAD" );
```

so the above codes give me the result of 7 cause it is in between of Two FIXED strings.

Comment: I think your `data` string is missing quotes?

Comment: split into array ... pop and shift ... that will get rid of first and last ... x = data.split('\r\n'); x.shift(); x.pop(); ... now x has the middle lines

Comment: By the way Anon, your code works if you use "20 FIXED" instead of "FIXED" but obviously you must be sure that 20 is only on the first line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the steps to achieve this:

Step 1.Convert string data to array by splitting with \r\n.

Step 2. Use **array.shift();** This removes the first element from an array and returns only that element.

Step 3. Use **array.pop();** This Removes the last element from an array and returns only that element.

```js
var data = "20 FIXED\r\n7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200\r\n 9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200\r\nLOAD 1 LOADTYPE Dead  TITLE DEAD";


function pullBetTwoStrings(data) {
     var result=data.split("\r\n");
     result.shift();
      result.pop(); 
     return result;
}

console.log(pullBetTwoStrings(data));
```

Comment: your explanation is very informative mate! Glad to see someone help out

Comment: @AnonSymphony thanks..please upvote if found useful for future reference

Comment: how do i extract a string if it's in between of a long string say there are additional string at the start and at the end?

Comment: You need to use regEx:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707299/how-to-extract-a-string-using-javascript-regex

Answer (score 0):

If your string pattern is always the same, you can use the Regular expressions like this:

```
var a = "20 FIXED\n\r 7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200\n\r 9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200\n\r LOAD 1 LOADTYPE Dead  TITLE DEAD";

if (/\d+\sFIXED BUT(\s|\w+|\d+)+(\n\r)/g.test(a)) {

    var result = /((\d+\s)(FIXED BUT)(\s|\w+|\d+)+(\n\r))/g.exec(a);
    console.log("this is result: " + result[0]);
}

/*this is result: 7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200

9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to end with an array of string but with a string your can use [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) as below:

```js
var data = "20 FIXED\r\n7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200\r\n9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200\r\nLOAD 1 LOADTYPE Dead  TITLE DEAD";
var innerData = data.slice(data.indexOf('\r\n') + 2, data.lastIndexOf('\r\n'));
console.log(innerData);
```