# How to extract string from url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript, parsing

API give url but I want get only specific string in url. For example:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-xxxx.appspot.com/o/folder_lib%2Fphoto_xxx-xxx-xxx.png?alt=media&token=xxx-xxx-xxx20-5-2016.csv?alt=media&token=b5d45a7f-3ab7-4f9b-b661-3a2187adxxxx

But I only want get: **photo_xxx-xxx-xxx.png**

How to split url at `photo` and end at `png`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a string using JavaScript Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707299/how-to-extract-a-string-using-javascript-regex)

Answer (score 0):

You can split by the string "%2F", get the last element in the array, split that by "? " and get the first element in that

```
const splitBySlash = url.split('%2F')
const filePath = splitBySlash[splitBySlash.length - 1]
const splitByQuestion = filePath.split('?')
const file = splitByQuestion[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

learn about [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

The regex to use is: `/photo_(.*).png/`;

see below how to use it

```js
var res = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-xxxx.appspot.com/o/folder_lib%2Fphoto_xxx-xxx-xxx.png?alt=media&token=xxx-xxx-xxx20-5-2016.csv?alt=media&token=b5d45a7f-3ab7-4f9b-b661-3a2187adxxxx".match(/photo_(.*).png/)[0];

console.log(res)
```

Here's a [nice app](https://regex101.com/) to practice and test yourself

Comment: Thanks for reply! I try this but get error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Comment: can you please send me the string? - following your example it should work

Comment: Thanks! I am use this string: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-xxxx.appspot.com/o/folder_lib%2Fphoto_xxx-xxx-xxx.png?alt=media&token=xxx-xxx-xxx20-5-2016.csv?alt=media&token=b5d45a7f-3ab7-4f9b-b661-3a2187adxxxx`

Comment: How are you using it? I updated my answer with the string you just post and it works. click on `run code snippet` it will show you the result